# Ruby on rails render partial does not execute javascript from the main form view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, program-entry-point, partial

I'm trying to execute JavaScript from the main view form, from the rendered partial when I click on the checkbox in the rendered partial but that JavaScript doesn't execute.  It only execute if I copy the content of the partial in the main view.  I've searched the site, but I can't get an answer.  This is what I have, for example:

app/views/people/_main_form.html.erb

```
<script>
  view something in partal
  $('people_visible_by_default').click(function(){
    alert("Can you see me");
  });
</script>

<%= bootstrap_nested_form_for @people, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'people_edit_form' } do |f| %>
   <%=  render partial: 'form_partial', locals: { f: f } %>
<% end %>
```

The checkbox to be executed in the app/views/people/_form_partial.html.erb

```
<%= f.check_box :visible_by_default, data: { preview_type: 'none' } %>

clicking on the visible_by_default checkbox doesn't show the alert as I expected.  How do I get it to execute when it is in the main_form.html.erb
```

Comment: ers
active oldest votes
up vote 0 down vote accept
 

No that was just an example. What I'm trying to say is how do I get that onclick from the main page to excecute in the rendered partial page

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

No that was just an example. What I'm trying to say is how do I get that onclick from the main page to excecute in the rendered partial page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using id of the checkbox("people_visible_by_default") as the selector in jQuery. But you forgot to append "#" before it.

So, try with

```
$('#people_visible_by_default').click(function(){
  //your code
});
```

OR

```
$('#your_form_ID').on('click', '#people_visible_by_default', function(){
  //your code
});
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

No that was just an example. What I'm trying to say is how do I get that onclick from the main page to excecute in the rendered partial page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the selector you have when loading the main page. Js iterates dom elements when loading main page. So if you rendering something by event (something unexisting in beginning of page loading), there is no js handler. But you can use selector of parent element of rendered partial. For example:

**view.html.slim**:

```
.parent_class
  = bootstrap_nested_form_for @people, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'people_edit_form' } do |f| 
   =  render partial: 'form_partial', locals: { f: f }
```

**view.js.coffee**

```
$('.parent_class').on 'click', '#people_visible_by_default', (e) ->
  do something
```

Try this. I hope it'll help you